# Propose to delete [ubuntu-lucid] tag or make it a synonym of another tag

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, tag-synonyms, synonym-request

I propose to delete [ubuntu-lucid](/questions/tagged/ubuntu-lucid) tag from Stack Overflow, or synonymize it with [ubuntu-10.04](/questions/tagged/ubuntu-10.04). If moderators will synonymize instead of deleting, I propose to add synonyms to other tags too:

- [ubuntu-11.04](/questions/tagged/ubuntu-11.04) - [ubuntu-natty](/questions/tagged/ubuntu-natty)
- [ubuntu-8.04](/questions/tagged/ubuntu-8.04) - [ubuntu-hardy](/questions/tagged/ubuntu-hardy)
- [ubuntu-8.10](/questions/tagged/ubuntu-8.10) - [ubuntu-intrepid](/questions/tagged/ubuntu-intrepid)
- [ubuntu-9.04](/questions/tagged/ubuntu-9.04) - [ubuntu-jaunty](/questions/tagged/ubuntu-jaunty)
- [ubuntu-9.10](/questions/tagged/ubuntu-9.10) - [ubuntu-karmic](/questions/tagged/ubuntu-karmic)
- [ubuntu-10.10](/questions/tagged/ubuntu-10.10) - [ubuntu-maverick](/questions/tagged/ubuntu-maverick)

Comment: Add [tag:ubuntu-11.10] - [tag:ubuntu-oneiric] as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think synonyms will reduce confusion and help encourage people to use the right tags.

+1 for the great synonymization of 10-11! (or 11-10 if you prefer)

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, it can be replaced with [ubuntu](/questions/tagged/ubuntu), since there is already [askubuntu](http://askubuntu.com).